# Optimal strategy for multiplying m integers

Tags: algorithm, multiplication, huffman-code

I want to understand how to optimally multiply m positive integers a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>m</sub> if I'm only allowed to choose an order in which I can make multiplications.
Each multiplication order corresponds to an extended binary tree with weights of external nodes w<sub>k</sub>=log(a<sub>k</sub>).
Let s<sub>1</sub>, ..., s<sub>m-1</sub> be the numbers inside the internal nodes, which are equal to the
sums of the weights in the external nodes of the corresponding subtree. The task is to find a tree which minimizes f(s<sub>1</sub>)+...+f(s<sub>m-1</sub>), f(n)=M(n/2), M(n)≈n*log(n)-complexity of the multiplication algorithm. Per Knuth's TAOCP exercise 2.3.4.5-17, if f'(x)≥0 and f"(x)≤0, then Huffman's algorithm forms optimal tree. Unfortunately, f"(x)>0 and Huffman's algorithm may not be optimal. What can be said in this case?

Comment: To make the connection between title and body of this post obvious, you could start the latter by spelling out how minimising *sum(x*ln(x)) optimises `multiplying m integers`. "Asymmetrical Toom-Cook" may render this (almost) moot for large numbers. My edition of TAoCP has only 12 exercises in 2.3.4.5, none that I deemed relevant?!

Comment: @greybeard, I corrected the question. I was talking about third edition if TAOCP [Volume 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming#Volume_1_%E2%80%93_Fundamental_Algorithms), 2.3.4.5. Path length, it has 17 exercises.